# Send Byte array as file in using http client in java

Tags: java, arrays, httpclient

We have byte array of file and we want to upload it as file.
`FileBody` only gets `File` as parameter but we have a array of bytes.

One solution is to save byte array into file and then send it
but it is not appropriate for me.

```
byte b[]= new byte[1000];
//fill b
MultipartEntity form = new MultipartEntity();
form.addPart("file", new FileBody(/* b? */));
```

thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do something like

```
HttpClient client=null;
byte b[]= new byte[1000];
MultipartEntity form = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cd = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(b), "my-file.txt");
form.addPart("file", cd);

HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase post = new HttpPost("");//If a PUT request then `new HttpPut("");`
post.setEntity(form);
client.execute(post);
```

Comment: which is the version used? I've used 4.0.1

Comment: Any way, he can use a `InputStreamBody` based on the syntax of the version used

Answer (score 6):

You can use [ByteArrayBody](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/ByteArrayBody.html) instead InputStreamBody or FileBody.

```java
HttpClient client=null;
byte b[]= new byte[1000];
MultipartEntity form = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cd = new ByteArrayBody(b, "my-file.txt");
form.addPart("file", cd);

HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase post = new HttpPost("");
post.setEntity(form);
client.execute(post);
```