# Camel: AWS-S3: File body null , when consuming file from s3 and passing to Rest api

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel

When performing Camel AWS S3 consumer to read files from S3 and pass them to Rest End point is failing, since file body becoming null. I used similar code for consuming file from sftp, it worked. But when i use Aws end point, it failing. Is there any other settings for exchange s3 object?

File body becoming null, when consuming file from s3 and passing it to Rest API.

Code:

```
from("aws-s3://test?amazonS3Client=#amazonS3Client&deleteAfterRead=false&delay=5000&synchronous=true&includeBody=true&autocloseBody=false&exchangePattern=InOut")
                   .convertBodyTo(byte[].class)
                    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "consuming", "Consumer Fired!")
                    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Replay Message Sent to file:s3out ${in.header.CamelAwsS3Key}")
                    .filter(simple("${in.header.CamelAwsS3Key} contains 'score_input'"))
                   // .to("file:target/s3out?fileName=${in.header.CamelAwsS3Key}")
                    .process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                            String filename = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, String.class);
                            File file = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
                            multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("file",
                                    new FileBody(file, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, filename));
                            exchange.getOut().setBody(multipartEntityBuilder.build());
                        }
                    })
                    .to(httpRoute)
```

Error:

```
2020-08-02 21:34:57,413 [ws-s3://ds_test] INFO  consuming                      - Consumer Fired!
2020-08-02 21:34:57,414 [ws-s3://ds_test] INFO  route1                         - Replay Message Sent to file:s3out input_0.csv.gz
2020-08-02 21:34:57,415 [ws-s3://ds_test] ERROR DefaultErrorHandler            - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-XXXXXX-Mac-49195-1596384290692-0-5 on ExchangeId: ID-XXXXXXX-Mac-49195-1596384290692-0-6). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File may not be null

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [aws-s3://test?amazonS3Client=%23amazonS3Client&autocloseBody=false&delay=50] [       218]
[route1            ] [convertBodyTo1    ] [convertBodyTo[byte[]]                                                         ] [       216]
[route1            ] [log1              ] [log                                                                           ] [         0]
[route1            ] [log2              ] [log                                                                           ] [         1]
[route1            ] [filter1           ] [filter[simple{Simple: ${in.header.CamelAwsS3Key} contains 'score_input'}]     ] [         1]
[route1            ] [process1          ] [Processor@0x7aa3628c                                                          ] [         0]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File may not be null
        at org.apache.http.util.Args.notNull(Args.java:54) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>(FileBody.java:97) ~[httpmime-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.camel.example.cdi.aws.s3.Application$AwsS3Route$1.process(Application.java:101) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.FilterProcessor.process(FilterProcessor.java:57) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Consumer.processBatch(S3Consumer.java:157) [camel-aws-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Consumer.poll(S3Consumer.java:101) [camel-aws-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [?:?]
2020-08-02 21:34:57,419 [ws-s3://ds_test] WARN  S3Consumer                     - Exchange failed, so rolling back message status: Exchange[ID-XXXXXX-Mac-49195-1596384290692-0-6]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File may not be null
        at org.apache.http.util.Args.notNull(Args.java:54) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>(FileBody.java:97) ~[httpmime-4.5.1.jar:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.camel.example.cdi.aws.s3.Application$AwsS3Route$1.process(Application.java:101) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.FilterProcessor.process(FilterProcessor.java:57) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120) ~[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Consumer.processBatch(S3Consumer.java:157) [camel-aws-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Consumer.poll(S3Consumer.java:101) [camel-aws-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102) [camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [?:?]
```

Comment: Please polish the question a little bit. It is hard to follow, since the code does not correspond stacktrace (stacktrace shows `convertBody`, which is commented out in your code sample). I dont think you can convert byte array to file. It worked with SFTP because it returns `RemoteFile`, which can be converted to `File`. Try `InputStreamBody` or `ByteArrayBody` instead, since you have already converted payload to bytes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406213/send-byte-array-as-file-in-using-http-client-in-java

Comment: @Bedla Thanks for throwing light on converting body. I resolved this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from("timer:CSVReader?period=10s")
          
                    
                    .pollEnrich("aws-s3://test?amazonS3Client=#amazonS3Client&deleteAfterRead=false&delay=5000&synchronous=true&includeBody=true&autocloseBody=false&fileName=")
                   
                         
                            .setHeader("CamelAwsS3ContentType", constant("text/csv"))
                    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "RESPONSE Headers ${headers}").end()
                    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "consuming", "Consumer Fired!")
                  
                    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Replay Message Sent to file:s3out ${in.header.CamelAwsS3Key}")
                    .filter(simple("${in.header.CamelAwsS3Key} contains 'score_input'"))
                 
                            .unmarshal().gzip()
                            .process(new Processor() {
                                @Override
                                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                    MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                                    String filename = exchange.getIn().getHeader(S3Constants.KEY, String.class);
                                    String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                                    ContentBody cd = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes()),ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, "temp.csv");
                                    multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("file",  cd);
                                    exchange.getOut().setBody(multipartEntityBuilder.build());
                                }
                            })
                    .to(httpRoute
```